# Как запустить из Python внешний .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Как запустить из `Python` `.exe` файл так, чтоб программа не ожидала завершения работы`.exe`, а просто продолжала работу?

```
script
  ↓
call_exe → exe working → ...
  ↓
without waiting
continue
  ↓
script_end
```

Comment: GUI или CUI? В первом случае достаточно `Popen` из `subprocess` : ```Popen(["notepad.exe"], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)```, если все же CUI - запустить отдельным процессом.

Comment: @gregzakharov, а можно ли как-то запустить блокнот с открытым файлом или сразу открыть файл через блокнот?

Comment: Конечно. ```Popen(["notepad.exe", r"C:\Oracle\notes.txt"], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например через [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile). Этот метод работает так, как будто файл запустили двойным кликом -- программы будут запущены, для файлов будет вызвана ассоциированная с ними программа.

Пример:

```
import os
os.startfile('firefox')
os.startfile('C:/firefox.exe')
os.startfile('C:/img.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.Popen("notepd.exe")
```

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python#2251026) и [здесь](https://python-scripts.com/subprocess) . Эта команда очень гибкая и можно запускать с аргументами.
Вообще это довольно интересная тема, связанная с процессами и потоками. В данном случае как раз вызывается новый процесс. Тот же функционал можно выполнить с помощью библиотек `multiprocessing` или `threading`.